# Jenkins unable to run Python file in Docker - file not found

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins

Added a Jenkins project with a job. Added a file called **test.sh** with a simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app image_name src/test.py
```

Jenkins supposed to run **test.sh**, create a docker container, run **src/test.py** and remove container:

```
builders:
  - shell: |
    ./test.sh
```

However getting an error

> - ./test.sh
>     python: can't open file 'src/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>     Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>     $ ssh-agent -k
>     unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
>     unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
>     echo Agent pid 1781 killed;

However `**src** and **src/test.py** do exist (checked it).

So what causes the error?

Comment: what is the result if you change docker run command in test.sh as `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app image_name /app/src/test.py` ?

Comment: Same *not found*. Tried `test.py`, `/test.py`, `src/test.py`, `/src/test.py`, `app/src/test.py`, `/app/src/test.py`.

Comment: When the image is created, you are in root's (most probably) home directory, which is `/root`. But your application is in `/app`. I think it's the problem.

Comment: I have found a solution that works: `docker run --rm image_name /app/src/test.py`. But I feel in this case like a monkey with a grenade. Do I lose something buy not specifying the volume? May be you can explain this - and put it as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution.